SPFx package-solution errors inexplicably
I have developed a full-page webpart that provides the user with an intuitive interface for managing SharePoint groups. I have used the same toolkit to build other full-page webparts.
When I run the following command line:
gulp clean; gulp build --ship; gulp bundle --ship; gulp package-solution --ship

I get the following results:
Build target: DEBUG
[13:16:59] Using gulpfile ~\group-mgmt\gulpfile.js
[13:16:59] Starting 'clean'...
[13:16:59] Starting gulp
[13:16:59] Starting subtask 'clean'...
[13:16:59] Finished subtask 'clean' after 167 ms
[13:16:59] Finished 'clean' after 170 ms
[13:17:00] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[13:17:00] Project group-mgmt version:1.0.0.0
[13:17:00] Build tools version:3.18.1
[13:17:00] Node version:v18.19.0
[13:17:00] Total duration:38 s
Build target: SHIP
[13:17:05] Using gulpfile ~\group-mgmt\gulpfile.js
[13:17:05] Starting 'build'...
[13:17:05] Starting gulp
[13:17:05] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[13:17:06] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 1.31 s
[13:17:06] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[13:17:06] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[13:17:06] Finished subtask 'sass' after 335 ms
[13:17:06] Starting subtask 'lint'...
[13:17:06] [lint] eslint version: 8.7.0
[13:17:07] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[13:17:07] [tsc] typescript version: 4.7.4
[13:17:07] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 1.13 s
[13:17:23] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 16 s
[13:17:30] Finished subtask 'lint' after 24 s
[13:17:30] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[13:17:30] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 333 μs
[13:17:30] Finished 'build' after 26 s
[13:17:31] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[13:17:31] Project group-mgmt version:1.0.0.0
[13:17:31] Build tools version:3.18.1
[13:17:31] Node version:v18.19.0
[13:17:31] Total duration:29 s
Build target: SHIP
[13:17:35] Using gulpfile ~\group-mgmt\gulpfile.js
[13:17:35] Starting 'bundle'...
[13:17:35] Starting gulp
[13:17:35] Starting subtask 'pre-copy'...
[13:17:35] Finished subtask 'pre-copy' after 77 ms
[13:17:35] Starting subtask 'copy-static-assets'...
[13:17:35] Starting subtask 'sass'...
[13:17:36] Finished subtask 'sass' after 246 ms
[13:17:36] Starting subtask 'lint'...
[13:17:36] [lint] eslint version: 8.7.0
[13:17:36] Starting subtask 'tsc'...
[13:17:36] [tsc] typescript version: 4.7.4
[13:17:36] Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 758 ms
[13:17:38] Finished subtask 'lint' after 2.76 s
[13:17:41] Finished subtask 'tsc' after 5.3 s
[13:17:41] Starting subtask 'post-copy'...
[13:17:41] Finished subtask 'post-copy' after 276 μs
[13:17:41] Starting subtask 'configure-webpack'...
[13:17:49] Finished subtask 'configure-webpack' after 7.96 s
[13:17:49] Starting subtask 'webpack'...
[13:18:36] Finished subtask 'webpack' after 46 s
[13:18:36] Finished 'bundle' after 1 min
[13:18:36] ==================[ Finished ]==================
[13:18:37] Project group-mgmt version:1.0.0.0
[13:18:37] Build tools version:3.18.1
[13:18:37] Node version:v18.19.0
[13:18:37] Total duration:1.07 min
Build target: SHIP
[13:18:41] Using gulpfile ~\group-mgmt\gulpfile.js
[13:18:41] Starting 'package-solution'...
[13:18:41] Starting gulp
[13:18:41] Starting subtask 'package-solution'...
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Found manifest: e27a9fe1-16cf-4f4b-adb7-6adb4d2d6c00.manifest.json
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Found client-side build resource: group-mgmt_208cc58d2fa303a9c823.js
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Found client-side build resource: group-mgmt_208cc58d2fa303a9c823.js.LICENSE.txt
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Found teams icons: e27a9fe1-16cf-4f4b-adb7-6adb4d2d6c00_color.png
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Found teams icons: e27a9fe1-16cf-4f4b-adb7-6adb4d2d6c00_outline.png
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Found teams icons: manifest.json
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Found teams icons: TeamsSPFxApp.zip
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Verifying configuration...
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Done!
[13:18:41] [package-solution]
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Normalizing solution information...
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Attempting creating component definitions for {1} manifests
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Created component definitions for {1} manifests
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Done!
[13:18:41] [package-solution]
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Reading custom Feature XML...
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Done!
[13:18:41] [package-solution]
[13:18:41] [package-solution] Validating App Package...
[13:18:41] Error - [package-solution]
[13:18:41] Finished subtask 'package-solution' after 36 ms
[13:18:41] Finished 'package-solution' after 40 ms
[13:18:41] ==================[ Finished ]==================
Error - [package-solution]
[13:18:42] Project group-mgmt version:1.0.0.0
[13:18:42] Build tools version:3.18.1
[13:18:42] Node version:v18.19.0
[13:18:42] Total duration:3.79 s
[13:18:42] Task errors:1
The build failed because a task wrote output to stderr.
Exiting with exit code: 1

You can see that, immediately after it logs Validating App Package..., it displays an error with no detail or message. What else should I provide to help troubleshoot this?

I found the resolution to this issue. I had apparently removed everything from the solution.features array in package-solution.json. I referenced another project, added the appropriate object definition to solution.features, and gulp package-solution --ship ran successfully.

You can try the followings:
gulp clean

gulp bundle --ship

gulp package-solution --ship


Not sure about gulp build --ship, but the above worked for me.
For more info, see Deploy SPFx and
SPFx Commands Cheat Sheet

Thank you for your response, but I was trying that before I added gulp build --ship and got the same results during the package-solution step.

Not sure why you are using gulp build --ship instead of using only gulp bundle --ship.  I've not seen any reference for build --ship

I added the gulp build --ship step as a precautionary measure after reading this question: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230539/spfx-gulp-package-solution-fails?rq=1.
